# How do I share one set of files with two different domains in Apache?

Tags: php, apache

I'd like to run my website in two different modes: dev, and test.  I currently have the site set up in `/var/www/mywebsite.com` and working fine.  Now I'd like to set up a different url that points to the same files, but has only one difference: apache's `setEnv`.  I want to `setEnv APP_ENV test` so I can then hit `http://test.mywebsite.com/` and read that `APP_ENV` in PHP.  Is this possible?

Comment: Agreed, and I did that by copying the regular config and changing the names, then symlinking like so: `ln -s /var/www/mywebsite.com /var/www/test.mywebsite.com`, and that "worked" in that I could `curl` the new URL, but it didn't pick up the `setEnv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two distinct Apache setups, it is best to use [Apache name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html). The key is to have two different configs, but use the same `DocumentRoot`. So for example this would be the Apache virtual host setup for `mywebsite.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com
  ServerName mywebsite.com
  ServerAlias mywebsite.com

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mywebsite.com.error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mywebsite.com.access.log combined

  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "prod"

  <Directory "/var/www/mywebsite.com">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And then do this for `test.mywebsite.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com
  ServerName test.mywebsite.com
  ServerAlias test.mywebsite.com

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/test.mywebsite.com.error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/test.mywebsite.com.access.log combined

  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "test"

  <Directory "/var/www/mywebsite.com">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I am assuming you are on an Ubuntu setup. So I would recommend putting them into two different files like this:

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.com

nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.mywebsite.com
```

Then symlink the configs to `sites-enabled` like this:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.com /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mywebsite.com

sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.mywebsite.com /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.mywebsite.com
```

Restart Apache like this:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then you should be in business with `APPLICATION_ENV "prod"` clearly going to `mywebsite.com` and `APPLICATION_ENV "test"` clearly going to `test.mywebsite.com`.